# Eslint - wrong error message? Detected incorrect braces with only single value

Tags: reactjs, eslint, package.json, husky

in a React/next.js project I have husky with eslint....
And... each time I get this info message in yellow:

```
⚠ Detected incorrect braces with only single value: `src/**/*.{js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css|md|html|scss}`. Reformatted as: `src/**/*.js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css|md|html|scss`
```

Here there are two problems, I think:

1. it doesn't reformat it as it says "Reformatted". When I go back to the package.json it still has the braces
2. I think that this is not a single value. They are pipe separated values. I think this error message is wrong.

Can anyone please suggest what's wrong and right and how to fix this issue?

This is the piece of code in the `package.json`:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css|md|html|scss": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix src/"
    ]
```

Comment: The extensions within the braces should be comma-separated rather than pipe separated. Since there are no commas, there is only a "single value" (`js|jsx|...|scss`), so it extracts that. The info message reports that it is reformatted internally, rather than rewriting the file.

Comment: Thank you, so in this case I'll make it comma separated. However isn't `--fix` supposed to rewrite the file?

Comment: I've never understood `--fix` to rewrite its own config files, only the files being linted :-)